# Owasp Zap and GitHub Action

Tags: github, action, owasp, zap

We have integrated OWASP ZAP in GitHub Action CI/CD. After scanning a web application, we then relayed the issues to the developers. After the developers have assessed the issues, they found out that some of the issues found are false positives. So the problem is, how do we configure ZAP to mark those issues as False Positives on the next run in the pipeline? We are using the stable version of OWASP ZAP Docker image. All of your inputs are much welcome, thank you!

I tried integrating a Jason rule file but GitHub ignore to take that into consideration

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can use a rules file.

- https://github.com/zaproxy/action-baseline#rules_file_name
- https://github.com/zaproxy/action-full-scan/#rules_file_name
- https://github.com/zaproxy/action-api-scan/#rules_file_name

`rules_file_name`

**Optional** You can also specify a relative path to the rules file to ignore any alerts from the ZAP scan. Make sure to create the rules file inside the relevant repository. The following shows a sample rules file configuration. Make sure to checkout the repository (actions/checkout@v2) to provide the ZAP rules to the scan action.

```
10011   IGNORE  (Cookie Without Secure Flag)
10015   IGNORE  (Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set)
```

Note: This TSV rule file controls only the result of the run it doesn't prevent any of the rules from actually being evaluated.

For further details on ZAP automation options refer to: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

Comment: I have tried that but zap seems not to take that into consideration while scanning. I have save my rule file into .github/workflows/rule_file.zap I have also use json formate but still not taking that into consideration. I use .zap and json as extension of my rule file but still not taking that into consideration while scanning

Comment: Just read please. As noted above the tsv controls only the result of the packaged scan not the execution/evaluation of scan rules. There is no json format for the rules file.